# Deserialize JSON using Objective-C into a custom object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using objective-c and trying to deserialize JSON into an array of a custom class called Blog. So the code below should generate three objects and add them to an array of objects.  I've looked at [this tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-and-json-part-2-deserialize-json-to-native-objects.html) but still ran into issues.

The JSON structure looks like this:

```
{
  "-KGN0p1I4YFI2YNOcbv3" : {
    "BlogDomain" : "blg1",
    "BlogName" : "n1"
  },
  "-KGN198bzC54opL47vUl" : {
    "BlogDomain" : "blg2",
    "BlogName" : "n2"
  },
  "-KGN66aqkhIxBAKTcFCx" : {
    "BlogDomain" : "blg3",
    "BlogName" : "n3"
  }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try out the below code:

```
NSString* path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JSON" ofType:@"json"];
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary  *object = [NSJSONSerialization
                             JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                             options:0
                             error:&error];

    if(! error) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSString *dictionaryKey in object) {
            Blog *oBlog = [[Blog alloc] init];
            oBlog.blogDomain = [[object valueForKey:dictionaryKey] objectForKey:@"BlogDomain"];
            oBlog.blogName = [[object valueForKey:dictionaryKey] objectForKey:@"BlogName"];
            [array addObject:oBlog];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error in parsing JSON");
    }
```

//Blog.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Blog : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *blogDomain;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *blogName;
@end
```

//Blog.m

```
#import "Blog.h"

@implementation Blog

@end
```

//JSON.json

```
{
"-KGN0p1I4YFI2YNOcbv3" : {
"BlogDomain" : "blg1",
"BlogName" : "n1"
},
"-KGN198bzC54opL47vUl" : {
"BlogDomain" : "blg2",
"BlogName" : "n2"
},
"-KGN66aqkhIxBAKTcFCx" : {
"BlogDomain" : "blg3",
"BlogName" : "n3"
}
}
```

[image]